# Triangulating a set of voxels

Tags: algorithm, 3d, triangulation, voxel

I haven't done much research on this yet, but i'm just asking around in case this has been done before.

Here's my problem:

I have a set of cubes of an arbitrary height, width and depth. These are either filled or empty. What i'm looking to do is develop an algorithm that is going to create an optimal mesh for this set of cubes by combining the faces of neighboring cubes into one.

My current idea is to step through the set 6 times(twice along each axis, once forwards and once back), and look at the set in cross section. Ignoring cubes that won't be visible from the outside, i'd like to build polygonal face for those cubes in that section. At the end of this, i should have (x+y+z)*2 of these faces. Combining them should give me the resulting optimized mesh for the voxel set.

I'm stumped on the triangulation process however.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a mesh from voxel data, the most commonly used algorithm is [marching cubes](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Marching_cubes).  However I suggest you search the net for *iso-surface extraction* for more advanced methods.